# Сколько IP нужно для сервера?

Tags: ubuntu, apache, сервер, debian, ip

Если подключить к серверу 2 IP и назначить каждому IP свою папку в VirtualHost.

1.Запустив скрипт из каждой папки с функцией file_get_content на стороний url. Обращение будет производиться с 2 моих IP?

2.Стороний пользователь интернета зная эти 2 IP адреса может проследить что они используются одним и тем же сервером?

Comment: 1) С одного из них. С какого - зависит от настроек и порядка инициализации. 2) 50/50.

Answer (score 2):

> Обращение будет производиться с 2 моих IP?

с того ip-адреса, который определён как «источник» при отправке пакета по маршруту до того ip-адреса, к которому обращаетесь.

пример. спрашиваем о пакетах, отправляемых ip-адресу `9.9.9.9`:

```
$ ip route get 9.9.9.9
9.9.9.9 via шлюз dev устройство src адрес-источника 
    cache
```

в ответе написано, что пакеты уйдут через `шлюз` с упомянутого сетевого `устройства`, в пакет как источник будет указан `адрес-источника`. слово `cache` информирует о том, что данный маршрут кэширован (для ускорения отправки пакетов, чтобы не вычислять маршрут для каждого пакета).

> Стороний пользователь интернета зная эти 2 IP адреса может проследить что они используются одним и тем же сервером?

разве только косвенно, на основании того, что маршруты от его компьютера к этим ip-адресам будут (скорее всего) совпадать. ну и не только **от его** — ведь в интернете полно сервисов, позволяющих отобразить маршруты до произвольных ip-адресов.

впрочем, максимум, что можно по этим косвенным данным утверждать — что компьютеры, обладающие указанными ip-адресами, находятся за одним и тем же шлюзом.

Comment: Спасибо. Очень подробный ответ